# AWS cognito custom domain A record without actual targer

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cognito, amazon-route53

I am trying to set cognito up with a custom domain. 
I have a registered domain name, hosted zone with route53. let's say mydomain.com.
I also created certs for mydomain.com, *.mydomain.com in us-east-1 (N.Virginia) as document instructs.
When I tried my domain, cognito gave me an error saying that I must have an A record. I tried creating an Alias A record. But I don't have an actual Target. I just was to use something like auth.mydomain.com for logging in.
Since I couldn't make sense of an alias record I created a regular A record and set the target to a dummy ip 1.1.1.1,
Since I read that the target isn't really relevant for cognito.
At first it didn't work. But I thought that it's dns proportion thing and I tested it the next day and was able to add the domain to cognito.

My questions are:

1. Did I do right? Is it ok to set the A record to a dummy ip as long as my domain doesn't actually point to anything?
   Is it possible to remove it after the association with cognito?
2. Why did it only work after a day? Is this DNA caching/propogation time? 
   Would that be the case with alias record? Or since alias is AWS aware it would be instant?

Thanks!

Comment: You’re using the hosted UI, right? If so, did you follow this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html ?

Comment: I did. And it's saying under prerequisites:. A web domain that you own. Its root must have a valid A record in DNS. For more information see Domain Names.  This doesn't say how I need to set up the A record. And that it needs to take time to be be in effect. Which are my questions.

Comment: Set the A record as an Alias and put the CloudFront distribution there... Something like d1234567899.cloudfront.net.

Comment: As I wrote originally, I don't have a target. There's no cloud front distribution. And it's actually not required, when I entered 1.1.1.1 as the target for the A record, eventually it worked after a day or so. And cognito gives you a CloudFront distribution for the hosted ui.

Comment: Use the cognito Cloudfront URL

Comment: cognito only gives you the CloudFront to use AFTER you assign the domain with the A record. But you can't assign cognito with the domain unless you have an A record. And since I have nothing to point it to. And so the questions remain:does it make sense/is it ok to do what I did, which is to set an A record for my domain.com with a target of 1.1.1.1.  And also why did it so long to take effect? How come it didn't work immediately and only the next day?

Comment: Generally speaking, your DNS should have an Apex record pointing to something...  If there's nothing yet, and although it is not best practice, then yes, 1.1.1.1 will work (or anything, really). Add that, then create the ACM certificate for your domain, make sure it covers your subdomain, verify it using DNS method which takes about 5 minutes, and then set your hosted Cognito UI in the UI as your subdomain and select your certificate.  I did this just now with a new domain and the entire process took <5 minutes to get my CloudFront url for my hosted UI.

Comment: That's great info. It was late and I probably didn't even wait the 5 minutes, I assumed instant effect. That covers everything, and yes, I will eventually have something to point to. Do you want to write it as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: All good! Glad I was able to help :). I've added the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, your DNS should have an Apex (A) record pointing to something. If there's nothing yet, and although it is 100% not best practice, then yes, 1.1.1.1 will work (or anything, really).

Once you add your A record, head over to Amazon Certificate Manager to create your ACM certificate for your domain. Make sure your ACM certificate covers your subdomain, and verify it using DNS method. Verification takes about 5 minutes and once your certificate is verified, you'll be able to head over to the Cognito console to set up your custom domain using the certificate you just created.